# Prove $\mathbb{E}((X+Y)^2|X^2+Y^2) = X^2+Y^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I want to prove, that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent symmetric $L^2$-variables, then

$\mathbb{E}((X+Y)^2|X^2+Y^2) = X^2+Y^2$    $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

but I have some problems showing this equation.

I can write

$\mathbb{E}((X+Y)^2|X^2+Y^2) = \mathbb{E} (X^2+2XY+Y^2|X^2+Y^2) = \mathbb{E}(X^2+Y^2|X^2+Y^2) + 2\mathbb{E}(XY|X^2+Y^2)$.

We already had that

$\mathbb{E}(X^2+Y^2|X^2+Y^2) = X^2+Y^2$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

So now I only have to show that

$\mathbb{E}(XY|X^2+Y^2)=0$.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are symmetric, $-X$ and $X$ resp. $-Y$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, so I get:

$\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(-X) = -\mathbb{E}(X)$

and so

$\mathbb{E}(X)=0$ (and the same holds for $\mathbb{E}(Y)$).

But how do I get now that $\mathbb{E}(XY|X^2+Y^2)=0$?

I'd be thankful for any help! :)

Comment: Hint: The distributions of $(X,Y)$ and $(X,-Y)$ are the same hence the distributions of $(XY,X^2+Y^2)$ and $(-XY,X^2+Y^2)$ are the same, plus the fact that conditional expectations only depend on joint distributions.

Comment: Thank you! So I can write $\mathbb{E}(XY|X^2+Y^2)=\mathbb{E}(-XY|X^2+Y^2)=-\mathbb{E}(XY|X^2+Y^2) \Rightarrow 2\mathbb{E}(XY|X^2+Y^2)=0 \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(XY|X^2+Y^2)=0$?